# delay display driver resume until spi bus is resumed

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have an embedded system running linux 3.0.101 in which the display driver should send via spi to a small micro controller a request to power on the display module and backlight boost converter as well.

This should happen at every resume cycle.

My problem is that the display resume function is called earlier than the SPI resume is called. In the SPI resume, we need to send some initialization codes to this small micro concerned with power management. Only after this all other devices can send to the micro requests for power.

I don't want to change the type of init for the drivers I already have (like early_init or similar), but rather I would like to create a dependency between my display and the SPI bus, so that the display is resumed only after the SPI is resumed.

the display driver looks like this:

```
static struct amba_driver clcd_driver = {
    .drv = {
        .name = "clcd-pl11x",
        .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe      = clcdfb_probe,
    .remove     = __devexit_p(clcdfb_remove),
    .suspend = clcdfb_suspend,
    .resume     = clcdfb_resume,
    .id_table   = clcdfb_id_table,
};
static int __init amba_clcdfb_init(void)
{
...
   return amba_driver_register(&clcd_driver);
}

module_init(amba_clcdfb_init);
module_exit(amba_clcdfb_exit);
```

And for the SPI we have:

```
static struct spi_driver mymicro_spi_driver = {
      .driver = {
            .name   = "mymicro",
            .bus    = &spi_bus_type,
            .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
      },
      .probe  = mymicro_spi_probe,
      .remove = __devexit_p(mymicro_spi_remove),
      .suspend = mymicro_suspend,
      .resume = mymicro_resume,
};
int _leap_driver_insmod(int majorNum)
{
   ...
   return spi_register_driver(&mymicro_spi_driver);
}
```

So, my question is: is this at least possible to create this dependency, and, if yes, how? Maybe some macros?

Thank you,
Seba

System description:
Power Management Microcontroller (PMM) connected to Application Processor (AP) via SPI
PMM controls power lines to AP, display, and other modules in system
there is a power line "always on" that powers PMM
AP is connected to display. It has internal TFT controller
AP has external SDRAM

In low power mode only PMM has power and SDRAM, the later being in self refresh mode. PMM receives external interrupt, ant returns from HALT to running state. Checks conditions and starts power up sequence on AP.
AP resumes kernel, as everithing is already in SDRAM (was in self refresh ).

Until this very moment everything works as expected.

Background story: PMM has some bug we suspect in siliciu, that is hardware on its SPI internal controller. So, the first byte he receives is garrbled. In AP in kernel SPI driver we have an workaround. If SPI resume is not triggered before other drivers, when display driver resume it will request to PMM via SPI to power the TFT and also the backlight and it will fail.

This is why is mandatory for us to have the SPI resume prior to other drivers that need to communicate to PMM.

Sorry for this telegraphic update, on mobile, between planes

Comment: You have to provide a high-level schematics that explains how power rails are connected to the devices in question. It considers voltage source(s), regulator(s), host bus IP(s), etc. Without that is tough to answer which way you should choose to solve your problem.

Comment: Updated original post. Thank you.

Comment: So, first of all you have to switch to use `struct dev_pm_ops` instead of legacy way. The problem might be workarounded by using `noirq` versions of PM callbacks with detailed description in the comment why you are doing so. I have no idea if it helps to all your devices since some drivers might still use same callback level. Second, but very fragile and unacceptable, is to change linkage of modules the way the SPI goes quite early in the list. But here as I can see is not trivial to fix the issue in a right way (on the first glance). I would recommend to write into *linux-pm* mailing list.